# What is the ideal memory block size to use when copying?

Tags: c++, file-io, memory-management

I am currently using 100 megabytes per memory block to copy large files.

Is there a "good" amount that people normally use?

**Edit**

Thanks for all the great responses.

I'm still quite new to these concepts so I'll try to understand a lot of the ones that have been said (e.g. write back cache). I keep learning new things :)

Comment: Perhaps your executable has a highed priority than Windows-copier.

Comment: If your OS offers 'statfs' then you can look at the blocksize it suggests (`f_bsize`), although I don't know how far you can believe that's it's actually "optimal". Unless you're really worried what happens on different platforms and filesystems, run a few tests on your machine with different sizes from very small to very large. There's no point using more memory beyond the point where it stops getting faster.

Comment: Also consider using native operations, such as `CopyFile` on Windows.

Comment: @MSalters, I would consider that if I didn't want to learn anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A block between 4096 and 32KB is the typical choice.  Using 100MB is counter-productive.  You are occupying RAM with the buffer that can be put to *much* better use as the file system writeback cache.

Copying files is very fast when the file fits completely in the cache, the WriteFile() call is a simple memory-to-memory copy.  The cache manager then lazily writes it out to the disk.  But when there's no more room in the cache, the copy speed drops off a cliff when WriteFile() has to wait for space to be made available.  It now goes at disk write speeds.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend you to benchmark this, and remember to include *much* smaller block sizes. In my own tests on this, I got quite counterintuitive results.

When reading and writing from the hard drive, all (power of two) block sizes between 512 byte and 512 kB gave the same speed. Increasing the block size from 512 kB to 1 MB *reduced* the copying speed to about 60%. Increasing the block size further increased the speed again, but never all the way back to the speed of using small blocks.

When all the copied data was in the cache memory, the (much faster) copying speed improved with increasing block sizes, flattening out around reaching 32 kB blocks, and then suddenly dropped to about half the previous speed when going from 256 kB to 512 kB blocks, never to return to the previous speeds.

After this test, I dropped read/write block sizes in several of my programs from around 1 MB to 32 kB.

Comment: On one occasion (a few years ago) when I ran a bunch of tests on mobile devices with Flash filesystems, write speed kept increasing up to about 256K or so, although with very diminishing returns past 64K. But IIRC I was just testing write from memory to file, not file-file copy. And we could never really figure out what was special about those sizes.

Answer (score 2):

There's generally little benefit in using blocks that large.

Suppose your operating system is super-naive and every read or write operation incurs a hard disc seek (in practice you will often find that writes get queued and reads get read-ahead-buffered, reducing the benefit of using large buffers in your application code).

Then every block costs you (say) 2x10ms for two seeks (one to read and one to write) and there's little point increasing your block size once the time for the actual reading and writing is substantially more than that. A really fast HD might read and write at 150MB/s, in which case that 10ms would correspond to 1.5MB of reading/writing, and you'd be gaining little for blocksizes beyond 15MB.

In practice, (1) your seek time will probably be less, (2) your read and write bandwidth will probably be more, and (3) your OS and drive hardware will probably be cacheing and queueing things for you; you'll probably see little or no benefit from blocksizes above about 100KB.

(You should probably benchmark a variety of blocksizes and see what you get on your own system.)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it depends on size of free memory that you have.

If you use 100 M blocks to copy on machine that has for example 30Mb of empty memory then it'll take much more time to copy than using smaller (20M) block.

If your buffor for copying is larger than size of available free memory then due to virtual memory swapping your copying will be slower than expected.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you mean but I check if the file size is bigger than 100 megabytes, and if its not I just use a block that is the exact file size.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty excessive amount. Consider that you don't even start writing data before reading 100 MB, so the filesystem driver doesn't even have an opportunity to write any of the destination file while you're reading. The disk could be writing parts of the file that happen to pass under the head as it's reading the source file (see [elevator seek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevator_algorithm) for example).

Answer (score 0):

Given that the drive must seek when it changes tracks, might not a block size of say 63 x 512 = 32256 produce optimum results?

Comment: There are a few layers of operating system and hardware between the physical disk and the program, so the disk track size is probably not important. However, welcome to SO :-).