# Splitting a file into several parts

Tags: c++, qt, split, copy

I'm trying to make a File copying application in Qt. I need to split the source file into several files so that my copy function can copy portions of data one by one and update the `QProgressBar`. To update the progress accurately I need to split the source file in 1% of its original size. Is my approach  wrong. I'm unable to find much resources on this topic.How can I split the source file into several parts of equal size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a self-contained sketch of such an asynchronous file copier. There are some shortcomings:

1. The error reporting needs to report QFile error codes as well.
2. A custom mutex locker class is really needed to deal with mutex RAII.

When looking at the code, ensure that you consider the implementation and the interface (its use) separately. The interface makes it easy to use. The implementation's relative complexity makes the easy to use interface possible.

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QProgressDialog>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QBasicTimer>
#include <QElapsedTimer>
#include <QThread>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QFile>
#include <limits>

class FileCopier : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   QMutex mutable m_mutex;
   QByteArray m_buf;
   QBasicTimer m_copy, m_progress;
   QString m_error;
   QFile m_fi, m_fo;
   qint64 m_total, m_done;
   int m_shift;

   void close() {
      m_copy.stop();
      m_progress.stop();
      m_fi.close();
      m_fo.close();
      m_mutex.unlock();
   }
   /// Takes the error string from given file and emits an error indication.
   /// Closes the files and stops the copy. Always returns false
   bool error(QFile & f) {
      m_error = f.errorString();
      m_error.append(QStringLiteral("(in %1 file").arg(f.objectName()));
      emit finished(false, m_error);
      close();
      return false;
   }
   void finished() {
      emitProgress();
      emit finished(m_done == m_total, m_error);
      close();
   }
   void emitProgress() {
      emit progressed(m_done, m_total);
      emit hasProgressValue(m_done >> m_shift);
   }
   void timerEvent(QTimerEvent * ev) {
      if (ev->timerId() == m_copy.timerId()) {
         // Do the copy
         qint64 read = m_fi.read(m_buf.data(), m_buf.size());
         if (read == -1) { error(m_fi); return; }
         if (read == 0) return finished();
         qint64 written = m_fo.write(m_buf.constData(), read);
         if (written == -1) { error(m_fo); return; }
         Q_ASSERT(written == read);
         m_done += read;
      }
      else if (ev->timerId() == m_progress.timerId())
         emitProgress();
   }
   Q_INVOKABLE void cancelImpl() {
      if (!m_fi.isOpen()) return;
      m_error = "Canceled";
      finished();
   }
public:
   explicit FileCopier(QObject * parent = 0) :
      QObject(parent),
      // Copy 64kbytes at a time. On a modern hard drive, we'll copy
      // on the order of 1000 such blocks per second.
      m_buf(65536, Qt::Uninitialized)
   {
      m_fi.setObjectName("source");
      m_fo.setObjectName("destination");
   }
   /// Copies a file to another with progress indication.
   /// Returns false if the files cannot be opened.
   /// This method is thread safe.
   Q_SLOT bool copy(const QString & src, const QString & dst) {
      bool locked = m_mutex.tryLock();
      Q_ASSERT_X(locked, "copy",
                 "Another copy is already in progress");
      m_error.clear();

      // Open the files
      m_fi.setFileName(src);
      m_fo.setFileName(dst);
      if (! m_fi.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) return error(m_fi);
      if (! m_fo.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) return error(m_fo);
      m_total = m_fi.size();
      if (m_total < 0) return error(m_fi);

      // File size might not fit into an integer, calculate the number of
      // binary digits to shift it right by. Recall that QProgressBar etc.
      // all use int, not qint64!
      m_shift = 0;
      while ((m_total>>m_shift) >= std::numeric_limits<int>::max()) m_shift++;
      emit hasProgressMaximum(m_total>>m_shift);

      m_done = 0;
      m_copy.start(0, this);
      m_progress.start(100, this); // Progress is emitted at 10Hz rate
      return true;
   }
   /// This method is thread safe only when a copy is not in progress.
   QString lastError() const {
      bool locked = m_mutex.tryLock();
      Q_ASSERT_X(locked, "lastError",
                 "A copy is in progress. This method can only be used when"
                 "a copy is done");
      QString error = m_error;
      m_mutex.unlock();
      return error;
   }
   /// Cancels a pending copy operation. No-op if no copy is underway.
   /// This method is thread safe.
   Q_SLOT void cancel() {
      QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "cancelImpl");
   }
   /// Signal for progress indication with number of bytes
   Q_SIGNAL void progressed(qint64 done, qint64 total);
   /// Signals for progress that uses abstract integer values
   Q_SIGNAL void hasProgressMaximum(int total);
   Q_SIGNAL void hasProgressValue(int done);
   ///
   Q_SIGNAL void finished(bool ok, const QString & error);
};

/// A thread that is always destructible: if quits the event loop and waits
/// for it to finish.
class Thread : public QThread {
public:
   ~Thread() { quit(); wait(); }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   QString src = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, "Source File");
   if (src.isEmpty()) return 1;
   QString dst = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(0, "Destination File");
   if (dst.isEmpty()) return 1;

   QProgressDialog dlg("File Copy Progress", "Cancel", 0, 100);
   Q_ASSERT(!dlg.isModal());
   Thread thread;
   FileCopier copier;
   copier.moveToThread(&thread);
   thread.start();
   dlg.connect(&copier, SIGNAL(hasProgressMaximum(int)),
               SLOT(setMaximum(int)));
   dlg.connect(&copier, SIGNAL(hasProgressValue(int)),
               SLOT(setValue(int)));
   copier.connect(&dlg, SIGNAL(canceled()), SLOT(cancel()));
   a.connect(&copier, SIGNAL(finished(bool,QString)), SLOT(quit()));
   // The copy method is thread safe.
   copier.copy(src, dst);
   return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually file copying with progress bar is done in this way:

1. open the source file (for read)
2. open the destination file (for write)
3. read a block (64 kB or so) from source file and write it to destination file
4. update the progress bar
5. repeat steps 3. and 4. until end of source file
6. done :) close the files

No need to split file into multiple files. Just process the file by small blocks (block after block), not whole file at once.

The "split file into several files before copying" approach is wrong - this split approach is equally expensive as copying, whole operation would took twice as long and you would need to update progress bar during this splitting too.

Comment: Thanks! How can I write the code that reads and writes only a block of source file. If I will use static copy function from `QFile` can I make it copy only a block from file?

Comment: You cannot use QFile copy because you have then no way how to get the copy progress. It is not possible to connect bytesWritten with it. There is a qt bugreport suggesting using file copy dialog: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-5874 Maybe you can look at source code.

Comment: I recommend not using QFile copy at all. Just open files, read and write by blocks and update progress bar.

Comment: Ridiculous? So how are files copied then? :) Btw. appropriate block size for I/O is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445341/what-is-the-ideal-memory-block-size-to-use-when-copying

Comment: @KubaOber: I do not understand whether you disagree with the "read block/write block/update progress" cycle I am suggesting or just the block size I used (4kB). Yes, we are talking about size of the read/write buffer in the application (maybe I should not call it "block".)

Comment: @Messa That buffer is too small. Its size is inversely proportional to the number of system calls, and also context switches needed to copy a file. Those system calls go through the abstraction of the C library and Qt, and since they block, they will context switch on a busy system. It's all very wasteful. Such block size was a good rule of thumb 15 years. Today it's woefully inadequate. The block size should be IMHO at the minimum `std::min(65536, std::max(file.size()/64, 4096))`. To minimize energy consumption on mobile, you'd want it even larger. All those calls cost energy.

Comment: @Messa Essentially, your bad advice costs unwitting users performance and battery life. It's just that: bad advice.